# Create a Fn with 3 inputs and return the number of values in the range btwn x&y evenly divisible by z. Code works but how to use STDIN and STDOUT

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT**

```
def evenlyDivisible(x, y, z):
    divcount = []
    for x in range(x, y+1):
        divcount.append(x) if x % z == 0 else False
    return(len(divcount))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x,y,z = map(int, input().split())
    print(evenlyDivisible(x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be useful to use `sys.stdin` and `.stdout` **here**, but you can do it in this way -

```
import sys # Import statement

# Function
def evenlyDivisible(x, y, z):
    divcount = []
    for x in range(x, y+1):
        divcount.append(x) if x % z == 0 else False
    return (len(divcount))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for lines in sys.stdin: # Should be used in for loop
        try: # This is how stdin is used
            x,y,z = lines.split()
            sys.stdout.write(str(evenlyDivisible(int(x),int(y),int(z))))
            # stdout only writes strings
            sys.stdout.write('\n') # Just a new line

        except: # Does this, if above code has any error
            sys.stdout.write('Wrong Input\n')
```